# Log request and response for all thrift servers

Tags: java, logging, thrift

I have multiple thrift servers running. In the order of requirements, I would like to do the following:

1. If possible, print the request method, request parameters and the time at which the request was made. IN addition, print the response time for the given call.
2. If the above is not possible, just print the request method and response method along with the timestamps of the scenario.

There does not seem to be any easy way to turn on logging for just the request/response instances. Note that the server is written/generated in Java. Any help on how I can get logging working for these servers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get all of the features you want, the best approach might be to simply wrap the service. For example, assume you have a service handler with a function `one()` and a function `two()`, the wrapper service handler would implement the same interface. Then in the wrapper service handler you would do something like this:

```
one() {
  print timestamp, method name and params
  call one() in real service
  print timestamp for call end
} 

...
```

You could even create a Processor Factory for the wrapper if you want to generate them per client.

Alternatively you could implement a ServerEventHandler, see:
 https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server/TServerEventHandler.java

These also get called per client request (via the processContext method) but acquiring the function name and params at the server level would be non-trivial and the processContext() method is only called once, before the handler is invoked, so getting the round trip time would also be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a mechanism called "**processor events**", 
look at the [`TServerEventHandler` class](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server/TServerEventHandler.java). There should also be an exmple around on who to use it, probably under `/test/java`.

You could also have a look at the [`TProtocolDecorator`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/protocol/TProtocolDecorator.java) class to intercept the calls. The [`TMultiplexedProtocol` class](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/protocol/TMultiplexedProtocol.java) could serve as an example how to use it.